# Basic split screen with css /html

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I'm attempting to create two separate divs, one covering the left half of the screen and one covering the right. Why does my code create only one div covering the left half of the page when I have included `float:left` and `float:right`? And how can I solve it?

```css
#col-1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #282828;
  z-index: 1010101010
}

#col-2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0080ff;
  z-index: 1010101010
}
```

```html
<div id="col-1">
  <h1>This is half of a page</h1>
</div>
<div id="col-2">
  <h1>This is another half of a page</h1>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5tzbxu5/#&togetherjs=MHjfejFNRt)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Comment: i.e. "...if 'position' has the value 'absolute' or 'fixed', the box is absolutely positioned, the computed value of 'float' is 'none'..."

Comment: Use flex-box instead. It's easier and way cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
#col-1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #282828;
  z-index: 1010101010
}

#col-2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0080ff;
  z-index: 1010101010
}
```

```html
<div id="col-1">
  <h1>This is half of a page</h1>
</div>
<div id="col-2">
  <h1>This is another half of a page</h1>
</div>
```

This worked for me. I changed `position: fixed` to `relative`. Also, they should both be float:left. The one on the right will become scattered if you do `float:right` for it, they should both be left.

Also, just a suggestion from me, that I like to do on my pages - I'm a big fan of tables, when used appropriately. Tables tend to put things right next to each other, with equal measurements and alignments. It does a lot of the styling work for you. Try doing something with `<table>`, `<tbody>`, and `<thead>` tags.

Comment: Side note about your suggestion on using tables: You should **not** use tables for anything else which doesn't require a table. Don't ever use them for layouts, it's a terrible idea and they won't work when it gets to adjusting the website for mobile (among other things). Their use as layout managers is highly discouraged. Instead, learn CSS and use it the right way. One good read: [**Don't** use tables for layout](https://www.thoughtco.com/dont-use-tables-for-layout-3468941)

Answer (score 8):

Using flexbox

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

#col-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
}

#col-2 {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
<div id="col-1">
  <h1>This is half of a page</h1>
</div>
<div id="col-2">
  <h1>This is another half of a page</h1>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit - My description of the problem wasn't fully correct, but the solution works none the less. Floats don't work well with position: fixed

```css
#col-1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #282828;
  z-index: 1010101010
}

#col-2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0080ff;
  z-index: 1010101010
}
```

```html
<div id="col-1">
  <h1>This is half of a page</h1>
</div>
<div id="col-2">
  <h1>This is another half of a page</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Code also includes a fixed positioning of each div, taking each out of the normal flow of the page, thus stacking them on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

this is the easiest and the shorter way to split screen.

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)
}

#col-1 {
  background-color: purple;
}

#col-2 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="col-1">column 1</div>
  <div id="col-2">column 2</div>
</div>
```